# TFS 2013 update M83

Tags: tfs

We are moving to new 2k16 servers with 2k14 SQL Server and 2k13 TFS Update 5.  I am attempting to install 2k13 TFS Update 5 and am receiving the following error:  TF400940: The selected database is a newer version than this application tier. You need to cancel out of the wizard, install update 'M83' and run the wizard again.  I cannot find any information about what M83 update is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I finally found the answer.  TFS 2k13 is not compatible with Windows server 2k16.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio Online, later Visual Studios Team Services and now Azure DevOps is released every 3 weeks. Each week gets a Milestone number. Team foundation Server is branched off of the Stars version at such milestone as well. M83 is the milestone at which TFS2015 was branched off if I'm not mistaking.

Meanwhile there was a new milestone M83, M85... M181 (2020.1) etc. Not exactly sure where we are now, but as you can see M83 is about 100 releases behind one of the most recent versions of it's cloud counterpart.

M83 was built around May 2015. So, you need to probably target at least TFS 2015. Given the number of bugs in the early versions of TFS 2015, I'd recommend making sure you target the latest version of the 2015 server.

What I'd really recommend is to pull the server forward to Azure DevOps Servers 2020.1